# Как округлить число? JavaScript,discord-js

Tags: javascript

[image: script]

[image]

Число x(78 строчка) получается огромным. Мне нужно его округлить примерно на 10 символов. Как это сделать?

Comment: Так вам надо округлить или обрезать? Учтите, это разные понятия.

Comment: Округлить,чтоб после запятой осталось примерно 3 символа

Comment: Так 3 символа или 10 символов?))

Comment: Убрать 10 символов после запятой чтоб было не 11.538461538461538 ,а 11.538

Comment: Если убрать 10 символов после запятой, то будет `11.53846`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для округления чисел используется метод [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Или, можете воспользоваться методом [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), но у него есть особенность.

```js
function roundDecimal(x, d) {
  const p = Math.pow(10, d);
  return Math.round(x * p) / p;
}
let val = 11.4536342323;
console.log(roundDecimal(val, 3));
console.log(val.toFixed(3));


val = 11.4;
console.log(roundDecimal(val, 3));
console.log(val.toFixed(3));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Ообрезание до определенного числа знаков после запятой и округление последнего:

```
const num = 12345.6789
num.toFixed(2) 
// '12345.68' - вернет строку
```

Если нужно просто обрезать, то:

```
Math.floor(num * 100) / 100 
//вернет число 12345.67, а количеством нулей 
//можно регулировать знаки после запятой
```

Answer (score 0):

варианты:

```
(11.538461538461538).toFixed(4); //к остатку дробной части + 1 итог: 11.5385
(11.538461538461538).toPrecision(6) // 11.5385
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: num.toPrecision(6) - это общее количество знаков числа, а не после запятой. Это не подходит.